# how to load dll from SDK addon data folder?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

We use web IDE for create addons. My test.dll situated in data folder. How to load it by js-ctypes?

With absolute path like "c:\test.dll" have no problem, but i cant use this path for distribute it.

```
var lib = ctypes.open("c:\\test.dll"); 
// works but how i get path to addon inner data directory?
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm giving you the way of least resistance here... There are other ways, like manually unpacking the DLL from your installed XPI, but that gets too broad, error-prone and complicated.

1. You need to define `"unpack": true` in your package.json, so that the XPI will be unpacked upon installation.
2. You need to use `self.data.url()` and various other tools to figure out the actual path of the DLL file. The URI might be wrapped multiple times in "resource:" and/or "chrome:" URIs before it becomes a file URI. So that need to be unwrapped too.

   ```
   const {Cc, Cu, Ci} = require("chrome");
   Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
   const ResProtocolHandler = Services.io.getProtocolHandler("resource").
                              QueryInterface(Ci.nsIResProtocolHandler);
   const ChromeRegistry = Cc["@mozilla.org/chrome/chrome-registry;1"].
                          getService(Ci.nsIChromeRegistry);

   function resolveToFile(uri) {
     switch (uri.scheme) {
       case "chrome":
         return resolveToFile(ChromeRegistry.convertChromeURL(uri));
       case "resource":
         return resolveToFile(Services.io.newURI(ResProtocolHandler.resolveURI(uri), null, null));
       case "file":
         return uri.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIFileURL).file;
       default:
         throw new Error("Cannot resolve");
     }
   }

   const {data} = require("self");
   let dll = data.url("test.dll");
   dll = resolveToFile(Services.io.newURI(dll, null, null));
   console.log(dll.path); // dll.path is the full, platform-dependent path for the file.
   ```

Comment: Thank you @nmaier! But {"unpack": true}  
`get:Error 403

FORBIDDEN
'Invalid key.
allowed keys: contributors, homepage, icon, icon64, id, preferences, license, permissions'`

Comment: Hmm. I tested on a clone from [add-on SDK repository](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/) and that worked for me... So the SDK has support. I assume you mean http://builder.addons.mozilla.org/ when you say "web IDE", so maybe you should file a bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=addons.mozilla.org&component=Add-on%20Builder

Comment: I ran into this lately, chrome:// didnt work, I had to make a file uri, or a regular system path (so file:// or C:\\blah\\..). so im guessing this still holds true huh?