# FF addon, js ctypes: couldn't open library (dll)

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jsctypes

I'm building a firefox addon that uses js-ctypes to load a C library.  This library is included in the addon itself (i.e. inside the "data" directory).  It works fine in Linux and OSX, where I'm loading a .so and .dylib file, respectively.  But when I try to load the .dll in windows, it fails with

Message: Error: couldn't open library c:\users...\appdata\local\temp...\customlib.dll

When I follow the path, the customlib.dll file is indeed where ctypes is looking.  When I open it with dllexp I see all the symbols, so I think the .dll itself is fine.

I'm not sure what info to provide.  This is how I'm trying to open the lib with ctypes

```
var {Cc, Cu, Ci} = require("chrome");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
var {ctypes} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm", null);

function resolveToFile(uri) {
    var ResProtocolHandler = Services.io.getProtocolHandler("resource")
        .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIResProtocolHandler);
    var ChromeRegistry = Cc["@mozilla.org/chrome/chrome-registry;1"]
        .getService(Ci.nsIChromeRegistry);
    switch (uri.scheme) {
        case "chrome":
            return resolveToFile(ChromeRegistry.convertChromeURL(uri));
        case "resource":
            return resolveToFile(Services.io.newURI(ResProtocolHandler.resolveURI(uri), null, null));
        case "file":
            return uri.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIFileURL).file;
        default:
            throw new Error("Cannot resolve");
    }
}

function getLibName(){
    return "customlib.dll";
}

var loc = resolveToFile(Services.io.newURI(self.data.url(getLibName()),null,null));
var lib = ctypes.open(loc.path);
```

I got the resolveToFile() from here [how to load dll from SDK addon data folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382201/how-to-load-dll-from-sdk-addon-data-folder), and it works like a charm in the sense that it finds the right path to the libs included in the addon.  But again, it won't open in Windows.

Comment: I also just tried hard-coding the path to the dll, and I get the same message.  Is there something I need to do to the .dll? e.g. permissions or something?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I missed this topic as I usually only look out for firefox-addon topics.

Comment: Also you might find this article here useful: http://mar10.noblogs.org/post/2014/10/02/loading-a-native-library-in-firefox-via-the-add-ons-sdk/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `var {ctypes} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm", null);` do just `Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm");`

is this code running from a ChromeWorker?

also do this:

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
ctypes.open(self.data.url('customlib.dll'));
```